# Renewal period when using quota in APIM policies

Tags: azure-api-management

The quota policies of Azure APIM work in strange ways.

We have a customer who we wanted to upgrade temporarily as a gesture after they ran out of credits. They made close to 100,000 calls, so we moved them to a plan that allows 400,000 calls until the end of their subscription cycle. As soon as the subscription cycle ended, we downgraded it back. By that time then made close to 110,000 calls.

To our surprise, they were immediately blocked by APIM. It appears that APIM simply looks at the number of last calls! What's with the renewal period then? Does the "renewal" never happen?

Here is the policy definition:

```
<quota calls="100000" renewal-period="2628000" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing the limit or the quota value will only increase or reduce the number of allowed calls within a given period but it does not reset the quota counter so if you are still in the quota period and you already passed the limit, you will get blocked.

So for example if your limit was 4000 every 1 hour and you made 3000 calls and you changed the limit to 1000 and the hour was not elapsed yet, you will get blocked as the quota counter is now equal to 3000 while the number of allowed calls is 1000 per hour so you have to wait until the quota period is expired so the quota counter gets reset and try again.

Comment: Thanks. The thing is, I was expecting the quota counter to reset according to the subscription cycles. Why would it not happen?

Comment: What do you mean by subscription cycles?

Comment: Sorry, bad wording. Say, the user subscribed a month ago, and that's also the renewal period. Shouldn't the counter be reset after a month?

Comment: No, your value is set 2628000 which is 30 days but a month might be 28 days, 29 days, 30 or 31 days so you can't calculate it this way. You can use this rest API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/current-ga/quota-by-period-keys to get, updates an existing quota counter value in the specified service instance or  this rest api https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/current-ga/quota-by-counter-keys to get update quota counters specified with the existing quota counter key

Comment: Ah! Thank you. So there is a way to update the counter.

Answer (score 0):

I have referred this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/quota-policy) wherein `renewal-period` attribute specifies the duration in seconds for the `quota` renewal.

```
<quota calls="10" renewal-period="3600"/>
```

Here I can make 10 requests within the 1-hour renewal period. Once the renewal period is over, the quota counters reset, and I can make additional requests within the new quota limit.

**Please Note**- `quota` works for policy scope level **product** only. You can use `rate-limit` policy for scope level **product/api/operation** and refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/rate-limit-policy).

I have tried the `quota` policy and got the expected results.

[image]

[image]

[image]

After making `10` requests, I have got the below error -

[image]

**Please Note**- Primarily I have set the Quota limit to 10 calls  and then I got blocked while making 11th call. As soon as I changed it to , I got blocked again as I have already made 10 calls which is more than the current allowed quota limit. I can make requests again after renewal period.

Comment: Sorry, did you read the question?

Comment: Primarily I have set the Quota limit to 10 calls `<quota calls="10" renewal-period="3600" />` and then I got blocked while making 11th call. As soon as I changed it to `<quota calls="5" renewal-period="3600" />`, I got blocked again as I have already made 10 calls which is more than the current allowed quota limit. I can make requests again after renewal period.

Comment: The whole point of this question is to find out why the renewal period does not work as expected.